# Remove or cancel OneDrive-d afther starting ubuntu 14

Tags: uninstall

I have ubuntu 14 and the programm OneDrive-d conform installation on my drive .

my question : 
How can I remove OneDrive-d from ubuntu
and how can I stop the automatic running afther reboot

with regards,
Bert

Answer (score 0):

Run the uninstall script.

Should be ...

```
./inst reinstall
```

from the directory where you installed it.

> how can I stop the automatic running afther reboot

That will happen automatically after uninstalling it.

Normally I would look in /etc/init.d and check the startup scripts. The daemon is called `onedrive-d` so it might be there and you can use `service onedrive-d stop`. That would be the Ubuntu way.

But chances are, if you followed the instructions, that you added `onedrive-d` to your start-up applications. Remove it from there.